# Will I have problems from waiting to grout patio tiles?

Tags: patio, grout, tiling

I laid porcelain tiles on my patio a couple months ago.  Life and weather has kept me from grouting the tile.

- Is a couple months between laying the tile and grouting too long?  What problems are likely to result?
- How long after a rain should I wait for the tile to dry out before grouting?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't be a problem. Clean out the gap between tiles with a garden hose (or pressure washer if you have stubborn "dirt" like bird poop), then blow out with a air gun and compressor. 
You only have to wait til it's dry after a rain (or washing out) before commencing to grout.

Comment: Do it before winter - otherwise water trapped in between the cracks will freeze and destroy your porch.